# Postgresql - Update using join and text column - Improve performance?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

Been strugling with this update, that I have to do using text columns instead of IDs (importing legacy data)

```
UPDATE contribs lc SET
       organization_id = (select o.organization_id from aux_orgs o WHERE UPPER(o.name)=UPPER(lc.committee_name));
```

I have 4.4 Million records on `contribs`, 4.2M match the subquery.
`aux_orgs` has 7185 records;

Current indexes (contribs)

```
    "idx_individual_contributions_committee_name" btree (committee_name)
    "idx_individual_contributions_organization_id" btree (organization_id)
```

aux_orgs

```
    "idx_aux_orgs_names" btree (name)
```

Is there anyway to improve on it? I tried running it for more than 6 hours with no success.

I am using a DB instance on AWS, Postgres 10.4

-- Using EXPLAIN

```
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on contribs lc  (cost=0.00..1030617572.50 rows=5114850 width=253)
   ->  Seq Scan on contribs lc  (cost=0.00..1030617572.50 rows=5114850 width=253)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on aux_orgs o  (cost=0.00..201.42 rows=36 width=16)
                 Filter: (upper(name) = upper(lc.committee_name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on an expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ind_augxorgs_name ON aux_orgs(UPPER(name));

UPDATE contribs lc
    SET organization_id = (select o.organization_id from aux_orgs o WHERE UPPER(o.name) = UPPER(lc.committee_name));
```

That said, if you are updating all the rows in the table, then the update will be very slow.  Sometimes it is faster to recreate the table rather than updating all the rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the expression index indeed improved the cost on explain, although I still think is quite high. @Gordon Linoff, Do you think, If i run an Insert (copying the table into a new one) using this exact same join, using the text columns, it will run faster?

Comment: @queroga_vqz . . . Yes.  It will likely be *much* faster.

Comment: Thanks, will try it and give feedback here.

Comment: Like night and day difference @Gordon Linnoff, it ran in just a few minutes. Thanks a lot! Will use this approach more often.